# template "ClassicThesis" doesn´t complie. Error aclabelfont undefined

Tags: classicthesis

I downloaded the Classicthesis Typographic Thesis template from this link [ClassicThesis link](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis) And it is not working properly.

I get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: \aclabelfont undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.131 \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}
[1]{\acsfont{#1}}
```

I follow the error to this code block included in the Classicthesis-config.tex

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{smaller}{acronym} % Include printonlyused in the first bracket to only show acronyms used in the text
\usepackage{acronym} % Nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis

%\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textssc{#1}} % For MinionPro
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\acsfont{#1}}
```

But i don't know what is wrong.

I have searched for information and I landed here [Similar error on ubuntu](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/117/classicthesis-42-texlive-2013-build) and here [error with acronym](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/95/fix-the-list-of-acronyms-causes-error) And I still cannont make it work.

I understand the template I downloaded may be outdated, I don't know if I will get more errors after this one, any ideas solving this?

I'm using Texmaker, with the latest Miktex available on Windows10

Comment: I think this was fixed some time ago. Get the template from the source: https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/

Comment: Just asked the powers of l-templates to update. Should be fixed within a few days/a week on l-templates.

Comment: Completely off-topic: Most helpers don't like that templte because it is a constant source of problems for new users. It just isn't a very well designed template and package (with the same name, so even more confusion).

Comment: I actually get the same error from the bitbucket links, and the I didn´t know of the existance of that package!

Comment: Please use the files from the branch  develop https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/8651517da332100f0e30233e45f6da0a590d7d2c/?at=develop.  This was caused by the changes in acronym package that were not quite backward compatible.

Comment: @Johannes_B It's a bit unfair to call for not using the package. The whole LaTeX is like this, things break from one to another version, packages stop working together for no obvious reason... Unfortunately, nothing better can be seen on the horizon. Classicthesis template was used to typeset at least 4oo theses in the last 1o or so years, that's quite a respectable number, don't you think?

Comment: If anybody want to know, I deleted everything related to that template, reinstalled [MikTex](https://miktex.org/download), downloaded the template from here:[Classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) And now it compiles with a few warnings.

Comment: @Paul please try the develop version from the link provided above. Many bugs have been fixed, and it will soon be released as v4.4.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Do you want to add an answer here?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Things do not generally just break and packages do not typically stop working together for no obvious reason. There are poor packages, sure. But package maintainers typically try to do somewhat better. Classicthesis asks for trouble, though, and gets it. It loads a hodge-podge of packages which are not designed to work well together and are in tension, if not quite conflict. The mixture of KOMA stuff with `titlesec` and `tocloft`. These come from different ecosystems. And then it loads other packages it doesn't even need.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I realise the package is well-intentioned, but it causes more trouble than it is worth. The best advise is always not to use it but to start from a cleaner class.

Comment: @cfr I agree, classicthesis is for the brave, and impatient who want immediate solutions. Not everyone is an expert in TeX/LaTeX, and most rely on copying the old solutions to their documents. Try imagining how much time a beginner could spend setting up a look similar to classicthesis. LaTeX package manuals are some of the scariest documents I've ever seen. I sometimes end up reading the implementation section trying to figure out what the package is intended for.

Answer (score 1):

This error started showing  after an update in acronym package that was not quite backward compatible. Try using the files from the [branch develop](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/8651517da332100f0e30233e45f6da0a590d7d2c/?at=develop). 
It's a fairly stable code, with many bugs fixed, that will soon be released as version 4.4.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how soon *soon* might be? Not in a hurry, just interested.

Comment: @Johannes_B A month or two, I guess. We'd appreciate a review of the code by any of the specialist from SE. Some things in the code are pretty ugly, we know, and most other are far from perfect. That shouldn't prevent us from improving. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody want to know, I deleted everything related to that template, reinstalled MikTex, downloaded the template from here: [Classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) And now it compiles with a few warnings.